# How do I restart the only failed process in one of the forked process in the systemd

Tags: systemd, process

I have the systemd file as below

```
[Unit]
Description=ACDS Relay Service (running on port 10400)

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/opt/liggable/relay/var/relay.pid
RemainAfterExit=no
ExecStart=/bin/bash /opt/liggable/relay/bin/start-acds.sh
ExecStop=/bin/kill $MAINPID
Restart=always
WorkingDirectory=/opt/liggable/relay
User=javauser
Group=javauser
PrivateTmp=true
TimeoutSec=90
SuccessExitStatus=1 143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Expected:**
The above `/opt/liggable/relay/bin/start-acds.sh` starts the two java process A and B within which the process B stop the process A for one of the operation during which I want the system to wait for sometime to wait for A to get started and if it doesn't then proceed ahead with restart of A otherwise do nothing

**Actual:**
The `/opt/liggable/relay/bin/start-acds.sh` starts the two java process A and B within which B wants to restart A ,on doing it the systemd has `Restart=always` which is restarting both the services A and B which is not what is expected behaviour.

Can someone please suggest what to do if I want to wait for sometime before the process B starts process A rather than systemd restarting it.

Comment: why not separate them in two service units?

Comment: Systemd does not know anything about processes A and B. It only manages the process mentioned in `ExecStart`. In case of a `Type=forking` service, systemd expects the shell script to spawn the main process and exit after that. Any interaction between A and B is internal to the programs A and B. If a `PIDFile` directive is specified, systemd expects the process to write the process id number of the main process. If the main process exits, systemd restarts the shell script (because of `Restart=always`). Btw, is there some reason why the service is `forking` and not `simple`?

Comment: @Bart I think that is the idle solution but I want to know if we control in other way rather separating them as two different units.

Comment: @JohanMyréen I have used forking as the once the start-acds.sh is the script which is spawning the two child processes in a cgroup but if I keep it as simple I will not be having the control for the restart of the services A and B that's the reason i have used the type as forking.